# How do I suppress the environment line when printing an R function?

Tags: r, environment, pretty-print

How can I suppress the environment/namespace line when I print a function from a package?  I've tried reassigning the function to the global environment.  I have tried entering into the foobar environment.  I've tried gimmicks and games, even with R to make this work.  It seems like there should be a simple way to do it.

```
> x2
function(x) {
    return(x * x)
}
<environment: namespace:foobar>
>
```

Comment: Why would you need it not to print? Are you trying to capture the function body? Maybe you want `body()` or `dput()`?

Comment: I need it not to print because I am putting it into a PDF with Sweave.  Both body() and dput() have the problem that they remove formatting and whitespace niceties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want to change how functions are printed, create your own `print.function`. I think this should work for you

```
print.function <- function(x,...) {
    environment(x)<-globalenv(); 
    base::print.function(x,...)
}
```

For example

```
x2<-function(x) {
    return(x * x)
}
environment(x2)<-asNamespace("stats")

base::print.function(x2)
# function(x) {
#     return(x * x)
# }
# <environment: namespace:stats>

x2
# function(x) {
#     return(x * x)
# }
```

Comment: This is looking good right now.  Let me play with it a bit more and I will let you know.  Though, for the life of me, I am not sure I follow how it works.